# Setting Checkbox Value in a serialized array in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, serialization

I am trying to get the value of a checkbox to store in my database, but my code crashes right after running the serialized array.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function () {

$('.form-signin').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serializeArray(),
        pname = data[0].value,
        score = data[1].value,
        cheatm = data[2].value;

    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
    var gs = new GameScore();

    gs.set("score", parseInt(score));
    gs.set("playerName", pname);
    gs.set("cheatMode", cheatm === 'true');
    gs.set("user", Parse.User.current());
.
.
.
```

It crashes after cheatm = data[2].value;

Here is the HTML:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading" id="login-greeting">Enter Game Score</h2>
                <input type="text" name="Player Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Player Name" required="" autofocus="">
                <input type="number" name="Score" class="form-control" placeholder="Score" required="">
                <input type="checkbox" value = 'true'> Cheat Mode<br>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not give the checkbox an id, and then set to the value to `$("myCheckbox").is(":checked");`?

Comment: That was a good answer. If you post it below I'll accept it - if you want.

Comment: I converted it to an answer.  Checkboxes tend to get weird sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the check-box an id and call it in JavaScript like:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"/>
```

jQuery:

```
var isMyCheckboxChecked = $("#myCheckbox").is(":checked");
```